# DatabaseFactory.CreateConnection() throws Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: wcf, windows-services

I have a client application consuming a WCF service throws an Error

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Details:

I am using WCF service with Microsoft Enterprise library for database connectivity, the service runs fine in the self hosted environment but throws an error if hosted as a `windows service`. I am not able to debug the WCF service, since it is hosted as windows service, so i tried using try catch blocks to find out, where the problem is.

I came across these two lines which i found to be most suspicious

```
Database db = DatabaseFactory.CreateDatabase();
DbConnection conn = db.CreateConnection();
```

I have already set my default database in config file. i think the second line must be the cause.

Please help.

Tried to find similar question on stack overflow but failed, hence posted.

> Appended Question statement with error snap + stack trace...

[image]

**stack trace**

at Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data.DatabaseConfigurationView.get_DefaultName()

at Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data.DatabaseMapper.MapName(String name, IConfigurationSource configSource)

at Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Common.Configuration.ObjectBuilder.ConfigurationNameMappingStrategy.BuildUp(IBuilderContext context, Type t, Object existing, String id)

at Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder.BuilderBase`1.DoBuildUp(IReadWriteLocator locator, Type typeToBuild, String idToBuild, Object existing, PolicyList[] transientPolicies)

at Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder.BuilderBase`1.BuildUp(IReadWriteLocator locator, Type typeToBuild, String idToBuild, Object existing, PolicyList[] transientPolicies)

at Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder.BuilderBase`1.BuildUp[TTypeToBuild](IReadWriteLocator locator, String idToBuild, Object existing, PolicyList[] transientPolicies)

at Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Common.Configuration.ObjectBuilder.EnterpriseLibraryFactory.BuildUp[T](IReadWriteLocator locator, IConfigurationSource configurationSource)

at Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Common.Configuration.ObjectBuilder.EnterpriseLibraryFactory.BuildUp[T](IConfigurationSource configurationSource)

at Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Common.Configuration.ObjectBuilder.NameTypeFactoryBase`1.CreateDefault()

at Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data.DatabaseFactory.CreateDatabase()

at WCFService.Service1.ExecuteSFDS(Cmd CmdObj, Int32 executionType) in D:\Projects\WCFService\WCFService\Service1.cs:line 32

Comment: It's hard to say what the exact the problem is, but 2 things you can try is 1: strip out the code and put it in a console application to debug, 2: Follow these steps to debug a windows service: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7a50syb3(v=VS.100).aspx

Comment: Ok... i was able to debug and found that the error is on the first line, that is while creating database.

Comment: Were you able to resolve it from the exception given while debugging? If not can you post the exception (inner as well)

Comment: @TBohnen.jnr, i was not able to resolve it, and i have updated my question statement for your reference, what i feel is, it is unable to find the connection string. what do you think?

Comment: see answer below, hopefully this works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am almost positive this is because the app.config is not copied to the output. Make sure that the config file is in the directory where your process runs from with the following name "YourServiceName".exe.config

If it is, while debugging see if you can use the ConfigurationManager to get the connection string, also, make sure the name of your connection string is correct.

**EDIT**

**End result from comment:**

I was missing the connection string in the output config file, and secondly i had defined the same endpoint and base Address, so i just changed the EndPoint address to "".

Comment: I have the app.config copied to my output, but i don't have the connection string there. As soon as i add the connection string, i get an error **Could not connect to net.tcp://localhost… TCP error code 10061** so i removed the connection string.

Comment: Detailed Error is "Metadata contains a reference that cannot be resolved: 'net.tcp://localhost:8010/WCFService.Service1/'. :: Could not connect to net.tcp://localhost:8010/WCFService.Service1/"

Comment: Ok, you should have it there, the error you are getting seems to be because of the connection string. Please could you paste the connection string so that we can have a look at it

Comment: ok, here goes the connection string...
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="DataAccessQuickStart"
   providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"
   connectionString="server=Server85\SQLExpress;database=myDB;uid=sa;pwd=PASSword" />
  </connectionStrings>
  <dataConfiguration defaultDatabase="DataAccessQuickStart"/>

Comment: Ok, so that error isn't anything to do with the connection string, it seems to be when configuring the wcf service. Can you perhaps edit your question to include the web.config. Do you have your service configuration defined in the app.config?

Comment: ok...Got it Resolved, i must thank you for everything, i was missing the connection string in the output config file, and secondly i had defined the same endpoint and base Address, so i just changed the EndPoint address to "". and now every thing is working fine... A dozen Thanks for each of your comment, those were very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

A Windows Service generally run under an identity of "Local System" or "Network System".
If your database connection using Windows Integrated Security, you will find it failing to connect to the database.

A quick work around is to run your service under named user on your workgroup/domain that has access to the database.

Comment: thanks for answering, but i am not using Integrated security for database connection. I have provided the connection string with Server, database, uid, password.